# Use container hostname resolution with network=host

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, docker, multicast

I have two docker container.
One is the "backend", the other "connector"..

The connector needs to have its network type set to "host" (To receive udp multicast: ssdp/mdns packets).

But it also needs to be able to use docker dns system so i can resolve container names to their ip addresses.

How can i do this?

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yml
version: "3"
services:

  database:
    image: mongo
    container_name: database
    hostname: database
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  backend:
    image: "project/backend:latest"
    container_name: backend
    hostname: backend
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - DATABASE_HOST=database
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - database
    tty: true

  connector:
    image: "project/connector:latest"
    container_name: connector
    hostname: connector
    ports:
      - "1900:1900/udp"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - BACKEND_HOST=backend
    depends_on:
      - backend
    network_mode: host
    tty: true
```

When i run it with `docker compose up`, my connector container throws a "EAI_AGAIN" error:

```
connector  | Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN backend
connector  |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:26) {
connector  |   errno: -3001,
connector  |   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
connector  |   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
connector  |   hostname: 'backend'
connector  | }
```

Which means the node.js app cant resolve the hostname "backend". Which is not a surprise since the network is set to "host".

How can have the "connector" container have its network set to "host" but is still able to resolve other container names?

Comment: AFAIK you can't have it be host, and also connected to a docker network. Why aren't you able to just put the connector service on the same docker network?

Comment: @Zoredache Because docker does not allow for a container to see multicast traffic on the host network/lan. Do you have a solution for that? If so the connector container can also be on a docker network. The only real issue is that the connector container needs to be able to react to mdns/ssdp packets on the host network. (Also send them)

Comment: Ah multicast complicates things a lot. Well you seem to be exposing the database and backend ports, so you could probably set the BACKEND_HOST and NODE_ENV variables to just be the external facing IP of the docker host instead of trying to use their internal names.

Comment: @Zoredache That works for sure, but then i cant use a docker compose file. Or how else  i set them dynamic? The nice thing about compose is, i dont need to care about this kind of stuff. And for a "quick start guide" for my application it should be as easy as possible for other to get them started, i thought docker was here good solution. Is it possible to work with static IPs in docker compose and keep the connector on the host network?

Answer (score 1):

Docker macvlan sets up a software switch(bridge) on a host network interface of your choosing.  This could be the same interface as the host, or a different  interface or sub-interface with a different network.

Assigning a container to this macvlan docker network will create a unique layer 2 address for the container and allow it to use any layer 3 ip address that has a route on the parent interface of the macvlan.  This will also give your container host network functionality, ie. mdns network discovery.

A container assigned to the macvlan network can concurrently be assigned to other docker networks in your compose file and communicate with the other containers within docker's networking.  Use the macvlan interface as nothing more than ingress for whatever data the rest of your stack is consuming.

Disadvantages and considerations to doing it like this:

- Macvlan configuration needs to be pointed at a physical named interface.  It also needs to be connected to the actual layer 2 network you are bridging it to.  Introducing macvlan into your docker environment will make it less portable.
- There's no proper way for macvlan interfaces to participate in DHCP.  Docker can be given a range to automatically assign to containers to the macvlan network, or you can individually assign a static ip to each container.  Be sure to remove those ip(s) from your DHCP scope to avoid conflicts.